# Count the number of <div> elements inside <li>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to know how many `<div>` elements are in each `<li>`. So something like that:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <div> Some image 1 </div>
      <div> Some image 2 </div>
      <div> Some image 3 </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div> Some image 4 </div>
      <div> Some image 5 </div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div> Some image 6 </div>
      <div> Some image 7 </div>
      <div> Some image 8 </div>
      <div> Some image 9 </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

The output of the function:

```
First <li> has 3 <div>
Second <li> has 2 <div>
Third <li> has 4 <div>
```

Comment: Is the literal output `First`, `Second` etc.. required?

Comment: @Esailija. If it does, it won't be DRY, unless you use a non-DRY plugin... And I ain't gonna write it all...

Comment: No, I nee to know amount to make if statements

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var lengths = $('li').map(function(){
    return $(this).find('div').length;
}).get();
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TcmNH/)

**Comments:**

```
// Make an array when the input for every iteration is a <li>
$('li').map(

// Every element in the array is the amount <div>s inside the current <li>
    return $(this).find('div').length;

// Produce the arry.
.get();
```

If you want to produce something similar to what you want **easily**:

```
$('li').each(function() {
    var length = $(this).find('div').length;
    $('<div> ' + length + ' li has ' + length + 'divs </div>').appendTo('#output');
});​
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/TcmNH/1/)

Output:

```
3 li has 3divs
2 li has 2divs
4 li has 4divs
```

Comment: Kudos for providing a live demo. Very much a necessity for proving it works.

Comment: @NateDSaint. Actually, though I love demos very much,  you can see it works. Shall I add comments.

Comment: @gdoron How can I access elements of this array later on? `lengths[0], lengths[1] and lengths[3]` ?

Comment: @CuriousProgrammer. Didn't get your question. Yes it's an array.

Comment: @gdoron. I mean, I want to have `if`statement: `if (divQuantity == 3) moveLeft(3px) if (divQuantity == 4) moveLeft(4px)` and so on

Comment: @CuriousProgrammer. `divQuantity ` of which `<li>` ? You should give more detials to what you want to do.

Comment: oh, sorry, I am making slider and if there is 2 divs in <li> them I need to slide to left for 200px instead of 300px and if I have only one element then 100px. I suppose I need to know quantity of divs of the last element.

Comment: @CuriousProgrammer. I think you should ask it in a new question is it's not so simple as you think, and probably can be done in a lot simpler way than you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Given a jQuery object representing your `<li>`, `item`, you can find out the number of `<div>`s that it contains just by doing:

```
item.find('div').length
```

But if you'd like a function with that *exact* output, you'll need a number → English library. Or, if you'll have exactly three, get your `<ul>` as `list` and do this:

```
var items = list.find('li');

'First <li> has ' + items.eq(0).find('div').length + ' <div>';
'Second <li> has ' + items.eq(1).find('div').length + ' <div>';
'Third <li> has ' + items.eq(2).find('div').length + ' <div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li').each(function() {
    console.log($('div', this).length);
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ZuSu8/)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li').each(function(i){
    console.log('<li> ' + i + ' has ' + $(this).children('div').length + 'divs');
});
```